# upload photo and photo size

Tags: php, mysql

I want to protect the website from a customer can not upload pictures larger than 2MB, and if do it,  receive an error designed by me. The code I created is this, but do not work, if the size is greater than 2mb, skip the restriction that sends him to "error.php" I try to upload the file, and displays a list of alerts

```
<?php session_start(); 
include("includes/conexiones.php");
$sql="SELECT * FROM trabajos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1" ;
$resultado=mysql_query($sql);
$fila=mysql_fetch_array($resultado);
$lastid=$fila["id"];
$prefijo=$lastid+1;
if ($_POST["cserv"]!=""){
$servicio=$_POST["cserv"];}
if ($_POST["cdirv"]!=""){
$direccion=$_POST["cdirv"];}
if ($_POST["cobserv"]!=""){
$observaciones=$_POST["cobserv"];}
if ($_FILES["cfoto"]!=""){
$foto=$_FILES["cfoto"]["name"];
$nombrefoto=$prefijo.$foto;
$Upload=$_FILES["cfoto"]["name"];
$Type=$_FILES["cfoto"]["type"];
$Size=$_FILES["cfoto"]["size"];
}
if($Size > 2097152){
header("location:error.php");
}
if($Size < 2097152){
$fototmp=$_FILES["cfoto"]["tmp_name"];
list($ancho, $alto)=getimagesize($fototmp);
$nuevoancho=600;
$nuevoalto=600*$alto/$ancho;
$nuevaimg=imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoancho, $nuevoalto);
$idnuevaimg=imagecreatefromjpeg($fototmp);
imagecopyresized($nuevaimg,$idnuevaimg,0,0,0,0,$nuevoancho,$nuevoalto,$ancho,$alto);
imagejpeg ($nuevaimg,"imagenes/grandes/".$nombrefoto);
$fototmp=$_FILES["cfoto"]["tmp_name"]; 
list($ancho, $alto)=getimagesize($fototmp);
$nuevoancho=144;
$nuevoalto=144*$alto/$ancho;
$nuevaimg=imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoancho, $nuevoalto);
$idnuevaimg=imagecreatefromjpeg($fototmp);
imagecopyresized($nuevaimg,$idnuevaimg,0,0,0,0,$nuevoancho,$nuevoalto,$ancho,$alto);
imagejpeg ($nuevaimg,"imagenes/peques/".$nombrefoto);
$sql="INSERT INTO trabajos (servicio, direccion, observaciones, foto) VALUES ('$servicio',         '$direccion', '$observaciones', '$nombrefoto')";
mysql_query($sql);
$idtrabajo=mysql_insert_id();
header("location:insertartrabajo2.php?vid=$idtrabajo"); 
}
?>
```

if anyone has a better solution, I'm open to advice.

thanks

Comment: While I appreciate that sometimes wheels need reinventing, there must be dozens off free and robust solutions to this kind of problem out there already!

Answer (score 0):

open your php.ini file, and update the parameter `upload_max_filesize` to 2M

Like this:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

save, exit the file and restart apache.

If you don't have access to php.ini, then add the following line to your .htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
```

I wouldn't rely on `$_FILES` variable because almost every value in that variable can be overridden by  malicious users.

When the user's upload exceeds `upload_max_filesize` then you just have to check  in `$_FILES['cfoto']['error']`.

Check that this value is UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE to detect if the file is bigger than the max size defined in your php.ini/.htaccess:

```
if($_FILES['cfoto']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE) {
  // redirect to your error screen
} else {
  // proceed as normal
}
```

Comment: thanks AlanChavez, but if I not use the variable $ _FILES, what variable use to upload photos?.

Comment: i have on my .htaccess file this code :  php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
php_value post_max_size 30M

Comment: @Ibantxillo so in your .htaccess you accept upload bigger than 2MB. Just change to 2MB, or validate the size.

Comment: @Ibantxillo you have to use the $_FILES variable to get the temporary path where the file is stored, but that's about it. I wouldn't trust any other data in that variable because the rest of the parameters in that variable can be manipulated by a malicious user. Let PHP handle the upload limit, it will throw a fatal error across your application if someone uploads a file bigger than 2 MB

Comment: I understand. but then as a hidden error to the error screen is to mine and not php. Let php generate this error, make me another error when deleting data, please find the photo that has not gone up, but gained their data. (sorry for the English, it is translated by google)

Answer (score -1):

For detecting file size use this code

```
$fileSize = $_FILES["avatar"]["size"];
```

and use this code for size u want...

```
if($fileSize > 1048576) {
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: Your image file was larger than 1mb");
    exit(); 
}
```

and the message.php is

```
<?php
$message = "";
$msg = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9.:_()]#i', '', $_GET['msg']);
if($msg == "activation_failure"){
        $message = '<h2>Activation Error</h2> Sorry there seems to have been an issue     activating your account at this time. We have already notified ourselves of this issue and  we will contact you via email when we have identified the issue.';
} else if($msg == "activation_success"){
    $message = '<h2>Activation Success</h2> Your account is now activated. <a     href="login.php">Click here to log in</a>';
} else {
    $message = $msg;
}
?>
<div><?php echo $message; ?></div>
```

Comment: Why are you using the $msg variable and trusting users to write to a page? What If I put message.php?msg=<script>alert('xss')</script> and then you 'echo' that unfiltered variable? That's a XSS issue waiting to happen.